# How to test pure JavaScript module with mocha.js

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, bdd

I'm trying to test simple frontend code. I just want to check with mocha that `myModule` is `object` and keys `length` greater then `0`.

Module definition:

```
var myModule = (function () {
    return {
        option: false
    };
})();
```

I'm trying to do so:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;    
var myModule = require('<path_to_my_moule_file>');

describe("myModule", function() {
    it("is myModule object", function() {
        expect(myModule).to.be.a('object');//I know it's not enough
    });

    it("is myModule not empty", function() {
        expect(Object.keys(myModule)).to.have.length.greaterThan(0);
    });    
});
```

But of course this didn't work. Because my module isn't a nodejs module I thought, anyway `myModule` returns simple `{}`, but not a real value of it (I'm trying strings, etc, but it always `{}`).
How should I test this kind of code?

**Update**:

And what if i wouldn't use modules at all?
Tested js file may be very simple:

```
var Config = {isDev: true};
```

Is it testable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add code like this at the end of your module:

```
if ( typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
    module.exports = myModule;
}
```

A typical browser environment does not have `module` defined in the global space, so this will export your module if you are running in Node.